# No puedo actualizar npm a su versión más reciente

Tags: npm

Ejecuto el siguiente comando que supuestamente actualiza npm a la última versión:

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

lo cual me devuelve:

```
/usr/local/bin/npx -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
+ npm@6.8.0
updated 1 package in 20.09s
```

Compruevo la versión con npm -v y es 3.5.2 en vez de 6.8.0

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

Comment: ¿Usas algún programa manejador de versiones?

Comment: Creo que no uso ninguno

Comment: Qué SO usas? Supongo que Linux pero qué distribución?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: Prueba a limpiar la cache: 
`sudo npm cache clean -f`
Y después:
`sudo npm install -g npm`

Comment: Muchas gracias! eso ha solucionado mi problema :)